# API manager 3.1.0 authentication failure

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

[image]

Having trouble with api-manager recently did an installation with identity and api-manager and once in while api-manager locks up and we have to do a complete restart. When looking at the logs you can see this error but when checking the published apis it seems the outh tokens are valid, am I looking at the wrong location.

Comment: Error logs say tokens are not valid. And there is no connection to it. Does it hang? How is CPU/memory doing?

Comment: Hello currently the CPU is jumps up to 99% and hangs there.

Comment: Issue was solved turns out that newer versions of Java were causing this issue once we replaced the version to 251 the cpu barely goes above 10%.